# Is it possible to create curved dashed lines with CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My objective is to create dashed lines like the ones I've highlighted in the images below. Is this possible with CSS only?

My web page is responsive using Bootstrap and if the width of the window changes, the dashed lines must be in the right position.

[image: Desired result, example 1.]

[image: Desired result, example 2.]

Comment: Those pictures have a jpg extension, but when I try to edit them into your answer, SO says they're in an unsupported format. Since I know JPG *is* a supported format, well, I'm just not going to open those I don't think.

Comment: try this link: http://s0.uploads.im/pWtA0.jpg

Comment: Try to make an element with dashed border-bottom, then use css to set correct needed width of this element (that will be width of your dashed lines) and then just set the right z-index values for circles (ex. z-index: 9999), and element that are play a role of your dashed lines (ex. z-index: -1)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The bad news is that you can't bend the dashed border. Its always be solid if you use border-radius in CSS. But as i think this example will steer you to the right solution.

```css
    #wrapper {
        width: 680px;
        display:table;
        margin: auto;
    }
    #wrapper > div {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .circle {
        position:relative;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #eee;
        border: solid 1px #ddd;
        z-index: 999;
    }
    .line-top {
        width: 120px;
        height:60px;
        z-index: -1;
        background: transparent;
        border: none;
        border-top: dashed 2px orange;
        padding: 40px 40px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        margin: 20px -50px 0;
    }
    .line-bottom {
        width: 120px;
        height:60px;
        z-index: -1;
        background: transparent;
        border: none;
        border-bottom: dashed 2px orange;
        padding: 40px 40px;
        border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%;
        margin: 0 -65px;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="line-top"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="line-bottom"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: As i check... only Firefox (and maybe IE) ignore dashed,and dotted line with border-radius... in chrome (chromium browsers) the borders are dashed/dotted ... not solid

Comment: I change the link of jsfiddle... now example is with inline-block divs

Comment: If the answer is fine for You please accept the answer.. not only upvote as you do... click the "check" under vote arrows